# How Make Div Sortable And Updating Value In Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to make my divs sort-able using jquery and getting their current new position so i can update that into database. i tried but not succeed. my code is

```
<div id="d">
df
</div>

<div id="d">
df
</div>

<div id="d">
df
</div>
```

jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#d').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: 'clone'
});

});
})
```

anyone please help me out .thanks

Comment: `id`s are to be unique, but you have 3 `id="d"`, so your `$('#d')` will only find/bind to the 1st `<div id="d">`. Either change to `class="d"`/`$('.d')`, or do an outer `<div id="d">` that wraps these inner `div`s to sort.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI sortable feature includes a [serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) method to do this. It's quite simple, really. Here's a quick example that sends the data to the specified URL as soon as an element has changes position.

```
$('#el1').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/your/url/here'
        });
    }
});
```

It creates an array of the elements using the elements id. So, I usually do something like this:

```
<div id="el1" class="ui-sortable">
<div  id="item_1">
df
</div>

<div  id="item_2">
df
</div>

<div   id="item_3">
df
</div>
</div>
```

Serialize option will create a POST query string like this: item[]=1&item[]=2 . So if you make use - for example - your database IDs in the id attribute, you can then simply iterate through the POSTed array and update the elements' positions accordingly.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
    // Execute statement:
    // UPDATE [Table] SET [Position] = $i WHERE [EntityId] = $value
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: then how to get the position value i.e 1,2,3 on php page ?

Comment: i have updated my answer with fixes.Right now it is working.Check now.Id need to be separated by _ eg :  id="item_1" and also class="ui-sortable" need to be added.

Comment: still same .. the code is same and giving the same error that item not recognize on php page

Comment: did you make the changes as mentioned.It is working for me in my local, i tested it , iam getting Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)

Comment: yes its working now .. thanks .. but if i sort div 1 and div 2 .. its echo the 1 and 3 ..